# Select2 using JSON as local data didnot work

Tags: json, backbone.js, jquery-select2

With reference to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161362/select2-use-json-as-local-data), here what I did in `render()` of my backbone project :

```
var topDepartment = serializeObjToJSON(nav.getTopDepartment(15));
//here is the result of topDepartment : [{"DepartmentName":"Test1","ID":56},{"Test2":"Professional Video Broadcast","ID":57},......]

function format(dep) { return dep.DepartmentName; };
$("#selCate").select2({
              dropdownCssClass : 'bigdrop', 
              minimumResultsForSearch : -1, 
              data:{results : topDepartment,text:'DepartmentName'},
              formatSelection: format,
              formatResult: format});
```

Here the html :

```
<select id="selCate"></select>
```

Running on chrome,there's no error showed even the `select` is empty. But in firefox `Error: Option 'data' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.` occured.

Problem : There's no any `option` in `<select>` when I run the page.

Any idea what could be causing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by doing this :

```
 $("#selCate").select2({placeholder: "Select a State",dropdownCssClass : 'bigdrop', minimumResultsForSearch : -1});
 _.each(nav.getTopDepartment(15),function(cat){
       $('#selCate').append('<option value="' + cat.ID + '">'+ cat.DepartmentName +'</option>');
 });
```

And this is html :

```
 <select id="selCate">
    <option></option>
 </select>
```