# How to Select Data from database using Ajax and Plugin Select2

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-select2

Please help me to solve my problem.

```
$("#kategori_laporan").change(function() {
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        $("#imgLoader").show();
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            url: "_views/getAjaxSubKategori.php",
            data: "id="+id,
            success: function(data) {
                $(".select-skategori").select2({
                    ajax: {
                        url: "_views/getAjaxSubKategori.php",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: function(term, page) {
                            search = term.toUpperCase();
                        },
                        results: function(datas, page) {
                            return {
                                results: data
                            };
                        }
                    },
                        formatResult: function(option) {
                            return "<div>" +option._sub_kategori_laporan+ "</div>";
                        },
                        formatSelection: function(option) {
                            return option._sub_kategori_laporan;
                        }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Data not showing to subcategory select. Thanks before.!
Screenshot >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2dJ8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Why are you firing an `ajax` request before you initialize the `select2` box? 
I ask this, because your `select2` box is requesting the search results via ajax as well. But maybe there is a reason. Please explain.

Then I can see in your screenshot, that your data returned from the `json` `ajax` request has not defined values `id` and `text`. If you are using other values ('_sub_kategori_id' and '_sub_kategori_laporan') in your json result, you have to tell the `select2` box, what is your `id` and `text` field. I think you can do this with the `processResults` method as described here:

[How to load JSON data to use it with select2 plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355083/how-to-load-json-data-to-use-it-with-select2-plugin)