# Use select2 with JSON file data

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2

I have a .JSON file with some school subjects that have courses in them. Every subject has a code and a name attribute. Some of them have these courses that are code and name pairs in a array in the subject.

```
{
    "bio" : {
        "name" : "Biologi",
        "courses" : {
            "bio01" : "Biologi 1",
            "bio02" : "Biologi 2",
            "bit0" : "Bioteknik"
        }
    },
    "eng" : {
        "name" : "Engelska",
        "courses" : {
            "eng05" : "Engelska 5",
            "eng06" : "Engelska 6",
            "eng07" : "Engelska 7"
        }
    },
    "sve" : {
        "name" : "Svenska",
        "courses" : {
            "sve01" : "Svenska 1",
            "sve02" : "Svenska 2",
            "sve03" : "Svenska 3",
            "lit0" : "Litteratur",
            "ret0" : "Retorik",
            "skr0" : "Skrivande"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like this to display in a select2 select input like this, giving an example with an ordinary select box:

[image]

The user should be able to choose both the whole subject, but also be able to specify themselves by choosing a course.

The select's option value should be the code of the object. Subjects use the their own three letter code, but courses first start with their subject's code, and add their own code to it. This is example code for the select above:

```
<label for="subject">Ämne eller kurs</label>
<select name="subject" id="subject">
    <option value="bio">Biologi</option>
    <option value="biobio01">Biologi 1</option>
    <option value="biobio02">Biologi 2</option>
    <option value="biobit0">Bioteknik</option>
    <option value="eng">Engelska</option>
    <option value="engeng05">Engelska 5</option>
    <option value="engeng06">Engelska 6</option>
    <option value="engeng07">Engelska 7</option>
    <option value="sve">Svenska</option>
    <option value="svesve01">Svenska 1</option>
    <option value="svesve02">Svenska 2</option>
    <option value="svesve03">Svenska 3</option>
</select>
```

How would I be able to use the data from a .JSON file with my select2 select input? Is it by AJAX request, and then, how would I go about to do that?

```
$("#subject").select2({
    placeholder: "Välj ämne eller kurs"
});
```

[image]

Comment: There are many examples of how to do this on Stack Overflow (and in the Select2 documentation as well, I'm pretty sure of that). Have you searched? Tried something? If yes, what? What did not work? If no, why not?

Comment: I have searched for examples but none of them used similar JSON data like  me. They used basic files with id and text pairs, which almost directly works with select2. I don't know how to structure the data request when I have this JSON data. I am pretty new to JSON.

Comment: I think this is pretty much exactly what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355083/how-to-load-json-data-to-use-it-with-select2-plugin

Comment: I have already checked that question, but I do not understand how I can use that with my problem. They have a different data structure, with a "ime" key for every item. I don't know how I should do it without any generic keys in my data. But please, if you know how to modify the answer in that question to answer mine, please do.